# Gauss-Seidel Method, differences from key in Python

Tags: linear-algebra, python

**Here is the problem**
equation 2: x<sub>1</sub> = 1/7(6 + y<sub>0</sub>) 
equation 3: y<sub>1</sub> = 1/5(x<sub>1</sub> + 4)

Define a function, called gs1_iteration, which accepts as input values for
x and y (which we think of as being x<sub>n-1</sub> and y<sub>n-1</sub> respectively), and returns a list
[new_x,new_y], where new_x is the updated value x_n and new_y is the updated value y_n
using the Gauss-Seidel method and equations (2) and (3).

In other words, gs1_iteration(x,y) should return the results of performing one iteration of the Gauss-Seidel method for system (1) on the inputs x, y.

To test your function, note that gs1_iteration(3,5) should return
[1.5714285714285714, 1.1142857142857143].

**So I know I have this first iteration right as**

`def gs1_iteration(x,y): 
    new_x=0
    new_y=0
    new_x = 1/7*(6+y)
    new_y = 1/5*(new_x+4)
    y = new_y
    return [new_x,new_y]
gs1_iteration(3,5)`

**returns [1.5714285714285714, 1.1142857142857143]**

**However, the next problem states:**
Define a function, called gs1_method, which accepts as input a single non-
negative integer n, and returns a list [x_n,y_n], where x_n and y_n are the values of x_n and y_n respectively for the Gauss-Seidel method when applied to system (1) above. Use
(x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) = (0, 0) as your starting approximation.
To test your function, note that gs1_method(2) should return the list
[0.9959183673469388, 0.9991836734693879].

**But my code returns a different value**

`def gs1_method(n): 
    x_n=0
    y_n=0
    for i in range(n):
      [x_n, y_n] = gs1_iteration(x_n,y_n)
    return [x_n,y_n]
gs1_method(2)`

**returns [0.9959183673469387, 0.9991836734693877], which is different in the last decimal place than the key shows**

From what I understand, my equation should work, as according to the Gauss-Seidel method, I'm using the new value of x and y for the iterations. Because I'm getting a different value, I think there must be some error in my equation. **What equation should I use for my Gauss-Seidel program, or what can I fix in my current equation to get the values provided in the key?**

<sub>I wasn't sure if this would have been more appropriate on stack overflow, but I think my actual problem is with my math, which is why I posted it here.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to be precise in the last digit? You would have to make exactly the same rounding errors, which would mean at least using the same order of operations, probably on the same ALU. Generally last digit is absolutely OK if you are not specifically working on rounding error problems.

Comment: The problem arises when I use my error function after this, which has the last 4 decimal places off after it iterates 3 times (and I know my error function is calculated correctly, because it's just the distance between two points). I'll talk to a TA about it, but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be precise, but I couldn't find anything wrong with my equation.

Comment: You might try to rewrite eqs as (6+y)/7 and (new_x+4)/5. 4 digits of after 50 iterations seems fine to me, if the math was wrong, you would be way off even with the first iteration.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Python stores these numbers as what are called floats, but you can manually change to another, more precise format to address this. Options are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663272/double-precision-floating-values-in-python).

Comment: @J.G., okay, I'll try using that and see what's going on.

Comment: Okay, the numpy float128 just returned my numbers, but a little longer each time (meaning, according to my code at least, they rounded correctly). I've got to talk to a TA and see what's going on. The class is experimental (Applications of Linear Algebra, and we're the test group, so not even the TAs know what's going on sometimes).

Comment: @Joe-You-Know You might also want to try changing `5` to `5.0` etc (in fact just `5.` will do). Failing that, I suspect your TA's approach used floats but got different result for hardware-specific or stochastic reasons, or because of a different Python "interpretation" running locally. I'm not an expert on what happens under the hood, but interpreted languages can be susceptible to that.

Comment: Okay, I talked to everyone in the class and the TA. They said not to worry about it and it's just a floating error. THanks everyone for your suggestions.